# I need drop down menu to close after # selection in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

In our mobile site we are using a hamburger drop-down menu to navigate to different sections on the mobile home page.  Our problem is that the menu does not automatically close afterwards.  The user has to click off afterwards to make the drop down hide.

HTML

```
<div id="menuSlideIn">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#item1">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item2">Academics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item3">Cost</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item4">Orientation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item5">Student Life</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
<div id="about">
                    <a name="item1></a>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder11" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        <div class="toTop black"><a href="#"></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

javascript

```
        $('#menuSlideIn').css("bottom", function () { return (-1 * $('#menuSlideIn').height()); });
        $("#menuSlideIn").toggle("slide");
        $('#menuHamburger').click(function () {
            $("#menuSlideIn").toggle("slide");
        });
```

css

```
#menuHamburger{
    float:left;
    padding: 8px 5px;
}
#searchImg {
    float:right;
    padding: 8px 5px;
}
.menuText{
    float:left;
    font-size:24px;
    color: #ffce00;
}
#menuSlideIn{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    background: #000;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100000;
}
#menuSlideIn li{
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#menuSlideIn li a{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an event handler to the links in #menuSlideIn that closes the hamburger menu.

```
$('#menuSlideIn li a').click( function() {
    $("#menuSlideIn").toggle("slide");
});
```

Comment: This worked.  How do I select a comment as the answer?

Comment: Just click on the "checked" grey icon right under the number of upvote for this post (you may have to wait a few minutes before checking it as a valid answer)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue , i close it down manually when it click on any of the navigation item (although i check that this should only happen when user is using mobile browser)